In summer when air temperature higher than 37 degree celsius, is it better to wear more clothes to keep cool？
Usually wearing more clothes will keep us warm, as we did in winter. In summer, we wear less to allow better heat dissipation to keep us cool.
However, according to the Second Law of Thermodynamics, heat spontaneously flows from higher to lower temperatures object. The healthy human body temperature is around 36~37 degrees Celsius. When the curriculum is higher than our body temperature in summer, is it actually better to put on more clothes to keep cool rather than to wear less? But this sounds really weird, I can't believe it is right.

Might work by definitions iff temperature outside is more than 38° celcius but human body will not get to perform properly eg sweat system. Ultimately causing heat stroke.

In middle east they dress warm at 40°C. Because it keeps the cooling sweat on the skin. Because it protects from the sun and heat. And they drink hot green tea to boost sweating.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You produce heat by essentially burning glucose. So if you isolate yourself your temperature will keep increasing. If the air temp is lower than your body temp you cool because of second law, but if it gets to hot you cool by evaporating sweat.
